# How to prevent Linux server from spamming?

Tags: security, spam, spam-filter, email-server

I installed mail scanner for spam protection, but is there any script for Linux to notify me or email me that some one spaming on my server ?

Comment: Which monitoring system(s) do you use for your servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about your "customers" who are authenticated users sending outgoing mail via SMTP.

There are number of steps to take which would make large scale spamming difficult.

Such as;

1. Rate limit outgoing mail per-user, to prevent large mail shots of UCE
2. generate weekly reports of outgoing smtp mail per-user, so you can see who is bulk sending
3. Require users to use correctly formatted RFC headers, which can block simplistic spamming
4. use spamassassin and MIMEdefang to alert on very "spammy" outgoing messages

The above steps are dependent on what platform and [what MTA](http://nixcraft.com/mail-servers/14441-sendmail-relay-throttle-e-mail-rate.html) you are using. I use logwatch to monitor the `/var/log/maillog`, but tools like munin, and collectd, or nagios can be configured to execute custom scripts to monitor per-user.

You can sign up for RBL monitoring services, which will give you a retrospective view of whether the server is being used to originate UCE, or other abuse mail;

http://mxtoolbox.com/services_servermonitoring2.aspx

http://blacklist-monitor.simplycast.com/Multi-Channel/blm/blacklist-smtp-check.html

Comment: it is very helpful for me.. thankyou :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Amavis-new with spamassassin and clamav, or RBL's such as Spamhaus or Barraccudacentral, these will cut down spam on your server a lot.

Comment: Outbound?  Or just inbound?

Comment: Thanks, but is there any script in linux ?

Comment: Will it slow down my server?

Comment: amavis will slow things down a bit, but its pretty negligible unless you have a very high volume of email to scan and a slow server.  RBL's are a simple reverse dns lookup, you won't notice any delay with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also monitor traffic and if you have unusual high traffic peaks this could be an indicator for spam. But this depends on what your server is used for. If it is a small webserver with almost no traffic then this technique will help you monitor unwanted traffic.

Comment: how i can monitor traffic for mails?